# How to add new membership if renewed after old membership expired (native CiviCRM / Drupal)

Tags: drupal, civimember

Consider this:

1. Wilma becomes a member on 1 Jan 2016, but does not renew at the end of the year.
2. (so throughout 2017, 2018, Wilma is not a member)
3. Wilma joins again in Jan 2019.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/renewals/), CiviMember will find the original membership and change the start date to 1 Jan 2019 and the end date to 31 Dec 2019, and set the status to live (or new etc.)

This now looks like Wilma has been a member since 1 Jan 2016, but that's not the case.

**Is there a way to have CiviMember create a new membership and leave old expired ones (i.e. those with "member: No" configured for their membership status) as-was?**

There's a [similar question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27343/create-a-new-membership-rather-than-renew-an-existing-one) that seems to be focussed on a WordPress/Caldera forms environment, but I'm asking about CiviCRM's native forms, hence the separate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible as of CiviCRM 5.4 at least.

The logic is coded in `civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php` so the only way to override this is with a core override file, which is a maintenance headache since it will need re-working on ever upgrade.

This patch seems to make it work as I think it should:

```
diff --git a/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php b/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php
index 18269014..7713ee9e 100644
--- a/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php
+++ b/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php
@@ -1860,6 +1860,14 @@ INNER JOIN  civicrm_contact contact ON ( contact.id = membership.contact_id AND
     $currentMembership = CRM_Member_BAO_Membership::getContactMembership($contactID, $membershipTypeID,
       $is_test, $membershipID, TRUE
     );
+
+    // -------Begin patch to create new memberships if last one had expired-------
+    if ($currentMembership && !$currentMembership['is_current_member']) {
+      // Force a new membership.
+      $currentMembership = NULL;
+    }
+    // -------End patch to create new memberships if last one had expired-------
+
     if ($currentMembership) {
       $renewalMode = TRUE;
```

Comment: If you leave the old membership expired and create a new one, does it open up potential false positives on searches for people with expired memberships?

Comment: Yes it does. It also means that if I search 'Current Member: no'  then there is a false positive because of the expired membership. I think this is the fault of the membership search though. I think the data should accurately reflect the truth, and I think the search should enable interpretation of that data back to real world truth. I don't think we should bend the data to fit the interpretation. But yes, this is important to understand and ultimately iron out!

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Far simpler than the other workarounds I'd seen. I am definitely happy to manually override this file to get this feature.

Comment: @AndrewWest You may be interested in https://github.com/artfulrobot/patchwork which auto-patches core on the fly (as in if you upgrade core it notices the change and reapplies the patch).

Comment: Some of the false positives could be removed perhaps with an approach of setting a previously expired membership to a different status eg Previously Expired. I think we took this approach once but do not recall if the client was happy to manage it manually or if we had a script/fix to do it

Comment: Just noting that this code is no longer in CRM_Member_BAO_Membership and has been moved to CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm. It's in a function called legacyProcessMembership() though so I imagine it'll change at some point

Comment: The Link posted by @artfulrobot is now located at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/patchwork

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but you could create a different membership **type** each year and disable the previous year's type. It sounds like you'd want these reported separately in reports anyway?

Comment: Clever! But I think that will interfere with the people who genuinely *do* renew their memberships each year, for whom we *do* want to see a continual membership.

Comment: Or at the end of the year add a tag to people who were members that year? (e.g. 2018 member, 2019 member, etc.)